# set width and height of an image after transform: rotate

Tags: css, html

i have a div with width: 190px and height: 260px, i assign img tag on that div, when i upload an image that shows how the image before, after that i rotate the image but the width and height of the image didnt change like the div, i have used inherit, everything about position and display, but no good at all..[image: state after upload] [image: the error thing]

Comment: Try changing dimensions but do not rotate and set its CSS `object-fit` to `cover`.

Comment: still can't, i have try this before

Comment: Try height width set to 100%;

Comment: i have too, no change, i am using max-height and max-width to keep the image resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hey,**

**Please Try this code.**

```js
var $=jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#RotateButton').click(function(){
    $('.col').toggleClass("afterRot");
 });
});
/* ----- IE Support CSS Script ----- */
var userAgent, ieReg, ie;
userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
ieReg = /msie|Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./gi;
ie = ieReg.test(userAgent);
if(ie) {
  $(".col").each(function () {
    var $container = $(this),
        imgUrl = $container.find("img").prop("src");
    if (imgUrl) {
      $container.css("backgroundImage", 'url(' + imgUrl + ')').addClass("custom-object-fit");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.col { position: relative; display: block; width:100vh; height: 100vh; }
.afterRot{ transform: rotate(90deg); object-fit: cover; }
.col img { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; }
.custom-object-fit { position: relative; background-size: cover; background-position: center center; }
.custom-object-fit img { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mob">
 <button type="button" id="RotateButton"> Rotate </button>
 <div class="col">     
     <img class="nor" id="rowImg" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*tSyuv3ZRCfsSD5aXB7v8DQ.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice answer that's why im looking about

Answer (score 7):

I have figured out an automated way as below:

First, I am getting natural height and width of the image (from onload trigger):

```js
var naturalWidth = event.currentTarget.naturalWidth
var naturalHeight = event.currentTarget.naturalHeight
```

Then I am computing a transform scale using aspect-ratio and generating transform style as below (pseudo-code):

### For 90deg (y-shift):

```js
const scale = naturalWidth > naturalHeight ? naturalHeight / naturalWidth : 1;
const yshift = -100 * scale;
const style = `transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(${yshift}%) scale(${scale}); transform-origin: top left;`
```

### For 270deg (x-shift):

```js
const scale = naturalWidth > naturalHeight ? naturalHeight / naturalWidth : 1;
const xshift = -100 * scale;
const style = `transform:rotate(270deg) translateX(${xshift}%) scale(${scale}); transform-origin: top left;`
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

> Inherit will not work.
>   Because you have to make the set the width of your image as the height of your parent. Then it will get completely resize in the parent element.

***image-width = parent-height***

Because after applying transform property width and height property will also get rotate in its respect.

**Sol 1:**
change the width of your image along with the transform property. (If it is variable then you can use the SCSS variables to assign the same values to the image-width and parent height.)

**Sol 2:**
This is not the perfect solution but will work in many cases. Add scale property to your transform property like this

```
transform: rotate(90deg) scale(.7);
```

Adjust the scale values according to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are not removing the class already associated with the Image. Try adding this to your button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#RotateButton').click(function(){
   $('#rowImg').removeClass("normalx").addClass("afterRot");
});
});
```

for a css like

```
.col {
  width:260px;
  height:190px:
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
.nor{
  width:250px;
  height:150px;
}
.afterRot{
  width:inherit;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

I have a sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bhaskar_nair2/aq9Laaew/22584/)